# How can I make sure that the browser started with Puppeteer is a normal browser and not an automated one?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, automation, puppeteer

I'm using Puppeteer to try to create an automation for Nike, but I can't log in even though I've done a lot of things.
I'm using puppeteer-stealth, but despite this the browser realizes it's an automation.
nike every time I try to log in it gives me an error.

I doubt the problem is in human movements etc, given that the browser notices something strange when opened.

[chrome erorr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1I2N2.png)

package.json:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "puppeteer": "^21.7.0",
    "puppeteer-core": "^21.7.0",
    "puppeteer-extra": "^3.3.6",
    "puppeteer-extra-plugin": "^3.2.3",
    "puppeteer-extra-plugin-anonymize-ua": "^2.4.6",
    "puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth": "^2.11.2"
  }
```

part of my code

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-extra');
const StealthPlugin = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth');
```

```
(async () => {
  const userDataDir = './user-data-dir';
  const chromePath = 'C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe';

  const userAgents = [
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Edge/91.0.864.37 Safari/537.36',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Firefox/89.0.2',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10; SM-G975F) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Mobile Safari/537.36',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/120.0.0.0'
  ];

  const randomUserAgent = userAgents[Math.floor(Math.random() * userAgents.length)];

  const options = {
    headless: false,
    defaultViewport: null,
    userDataDir: userDataDir,
    executablePath: chromePath,
    args: [
      '--start-maximized',
      '--disable-gpu',
      '--disable-infobars',
      '--disable-extensions',
      '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
      '--no-first-run',
      '--disable-software-rasterizer',
      '--lang=it-IT',
      '--disable-geolocation',
      `--user-agent=${randomUserAgent}`,
    ],
    ignoreDefaultArgs: ['--enable-automation'],
  };

  const browser = await puppeteer.launch(options);
```

Answer (score 0):

Nike uses akamai, you can google "akamai nike" to get more details.

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for the advice, I looked online a bit, but I couldn't find any solution. also because when doing the browser and javascript fp tests, my browser and that of my program give the same flags. if you know of some github repository or some site that can help me I would be very pleased; Even a simple Chrome startup done right is enough for me.